# Requests are failing sending from installed APK, but working fine using the simulator and same phone connected to Android Studio, why?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have successfully tested and created my first app with Flutter. Tested both on Simulator (Pixel 3 API 29) and also tested to run it directly on my phone which is Mi A2 with Android v9. I have no problem using the app and all the functionality, but when I create an APK file using Android Studio - Build - Flutter - Build APK file and then install it on the same phone and I try to login I get an error message - **There was an error, please try again**. I am using my own API and server to communicate with the app and I have created a debug entry in the DB every time the app is sending a request to the server, but when using the installed APK file I don't even get an entry that the app is reaching the server. I am new to Flutter/Android Studio and it will be great if u can help me debug this problem.

This is my code that I have wrote to login in case you need it

```
Future<void> _submit() async {
  if (!_formKey.currentState.validate() &&
      (_authMode == AuthMode.Login || _authMode == AuthMode.Signup)) {
    print('Validation Failed');
    // Invalid!
    return;
  }
  if (!_agreeWithTerms && _authMode == AuthMode.Signup) {
    ErrorDialog()
        .showErrorDialog(context, 'Agree with Terms and Conditions');
    return;
  }
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  try {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      // Log user in
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
          .signin(_authData['email'], _authData['password']);
    } else if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup) {
      // Sign user up
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
          _authData['name'],
          _authData['phone']);
    } else {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
          .forgotPass(_authData['email']);
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Forgot password'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Text('You will receive an email. Follow the instructions')),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/auth');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return;
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/qr');
  } on HttpException catch (error) {
    print(error);
    var errorMessage = 'Възникна грешка';
    if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
      errorMessage = 'This email already exists';
    }
    ErrorDialog().showErrorDialog(context, errorMessage);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
    // I am getting error, but I don't know how to debug using
    // the APK and see what is inside this error value
    const errorMessage = 'There was an error, please try again';
    ErrorDialog().showErrorDialog(context, errorMessage);
  }

  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

I am using Flutter and Android Studio. This is my output from `flutter docktor`

```
doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Linux, locale bg_BG.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /home/dimitar/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (преди 3 дена), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/dimitar/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Update**: I am getting this error when I am creating my APK file, but the file is created and I have installed it successfully. I don't know if this error have anything to do with my problem

> flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.6+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25:
>   warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has
>   been deprecated
>       setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
>                           ^                                                                                           1 warning
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

**Update2**: I downgraded the version of shared_preferences to ^0.5.3+5 and I don't see the error mention above anymore when building the app, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because I did not know that when you first build an APK file you first need to `enable` so to say the internet, so the installed/released APK file can have access to the internet. So the solution was to add this line of code inside this file - **Android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Now everything is working!